# Debug mode runs, release fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to put my asp.net app to production. But when I run the application in Production, a certain route doesnt work that well. It says that post.Author == null. When I run the application in debug, it runs well, even without breakpoints.

I tried the application in a release build or just with the start button in rider, both doesnt work.

Thats the route I am trying to debug. I have the problem with some other routes, too.

```
[HttpGet("public/{orgId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<PostModel>>> GetAllPublicPostsByOrgId(string orgId)
{
    List<PostModel> posts = await _postRepository.GetAllPostsByOrgId(orgId);
    posts.ForEach(async post =>
    {
        UserModel author = await _userRepository.GetUserById(post.AuthorId);
        UserModel saveAuthor = new UserModel();
        saveAuthor.FirstName = author.FirstName;
        saveAuthor.LastName = author.LastName;
        post.Author = saveAuthor;
    });

    return Ok(from post in posts where post.Published select post);
}
```

The author should be null, it should be an object with the attributes.

Edit: I tried to use `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]` on that router. That didnt work, too.

Comment: Do you really want to fire off all the code in the `ForEach` and forget it?  I'd suggest switching to a `foreach(var post in posts)`.

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. Post an answer and I can give you credit for that. @juharr

Comment: Also you might want to have your repository populate the Author when getting the `PostModel` so that you don't have to do what I'm guessing is multiple DB queries.

Comment: Yea of course, but if a user updates, I dont want to update all posts with that author. So I just save the authorid at the object and then I can query the user with up to date information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the lambda you use in the `ForEach` is basically a `async void` method which means it's fire and forget.  So your code is going to get to the `return` before it finishes setting all the `Author` properties.  Instead you should use a normal `foreach(var post in posts)` so the method will wait for all the `Author` properties to be set.  Note the reason this likely only fails in release is because this is a race condition and debug probably slows stuff down just enough for it to not happen.

Alternatively you could make the code into a method and instead execute it in parallel and then wait for all the tasks to complete before returning.

```
[HttpGet("public/{orgId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<PostModel>>> GetAllPublicPostsByOrgId(string orgId)
{
    List<PostModel> posts = await _postRepository.GetAllPostsByOrgId(orgId);
    var authorSetTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach(var post in posts)
    {
        authorSetTasks.Add(SetAuthor(post));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(authorSetTasks);
    return Ok(from post in posts where post.Published select post);
}

private async Task SetAuthor(PostModel post)
{
    UserModel author = await _userRepository.GetUserById(post.AuthorId);
    UserModel saveAuthor = new UserModel();
    saveAuthor.FirstName = author.FirstName;
    saveAuthor.LastName = author.LastName;
    post.Author = saveAuthor;
}
```